# What is the benefit of assigning null to some parameters in construct?

Tags: magento2

Not sure if it is Magento related question. But need to understand this.

I have seen some of the parameters in construct are assigned to null value.

For example:

```
/**
 * Initialize dependencies.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
 * @param AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
 * @param array $data
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json|null $serializer
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $extensionFactory,
        $customAttributeFactory,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
    $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

`\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null` is assigned to null. And in the function it is assigned to object.

```
$this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done for backward compatibility. For instance, if a class was inherited and the child class doesn't specify the needed argument the class initialization doesn't fail, the missed dependency will be initialized by `ObjectManager`.

Such workaround was added in Magento 2.2.0 release when all public code was marked as `@api` to don't break extensions which might use the private code. Starting from 2.2.0, the code which not marked as `@api` might be changed in a patch release and it won't be a breaking change because other classes should not depend on the private implementation.

For more details, please, see [Adding a constructor parameter](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/contributor-guide/backward-compatible-development/) section in the official documentation.